# Problem programmatically saving url_key for category

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I am using Magento CE 1.9.1.0.  I can't seem to get the category URL key to save properly.  If I add the category through the admin panel, everything works fine.  But I am trying to add the categories programatically.

The problem is that the url_key that I am setting is being ignored, and a differnet url_key is being generated based on the name of the category.

```
$storeId = 3; // my store ID
$parentId = 18; // the root category ID
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->setName('Contact Us');
$category->setIsActive(1);
$category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
$category->setIsAnchor(0);
$category->setStoreId($storeId);
$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
$category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
$category->setUrlKey('customer-service-contact-us');
$category->setIncludeInMenu(false);
$category->save();
$savedCategoryId = $category->getId();
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($savedCategoryId);
var_dump($category->getUrlKey());
// I get 'contact-us' instead of 'customer-service-contact-us'
```

I expected to get 'customer-service-contact-us' for the url key, but instead I'm getting the auto-generated url key 'contact-us'.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  I've tried disabling all 3rd party modules, but the problem still happens.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the store ID.

Before:

```
$storeId = 3; // my store ID
```

After:

```
$storeId = 0; // my store ID
```

Even though 3 is the correct store ID, the category model won't save the custom url_key unless you set the store ID to 0 (all stores).